# Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, showdialog

In my project, i have used to show the Form as dialog by using "ShowDialog()" method. But it throws below exception

**"Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog."**

```
Form frm = new Form();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Please let me know the reason of this exception. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `MDI` and `Form` is a child form then error is telling you that the child form is not top-level form which needs to interact with the parent form. "A modal form means it must be closed or hidden before you can continue working with the rest of application". This is why using `ShowDialog()` will have this error and where @S.Petrosov's answer comes in and where you should use `Show()` instead.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think he just need to pass this(the owner form) to ShowDialog instead of using Show.

Comment: Yes 'Samvel' is correct, my problem when I was looking at the code, is that they were passing an owner to the mdiform.  You don't have to pass an owner at all when you want to 'ShowDialog()'  The toplevel item has the owner of the Mdiform.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass owner `Form` to `Form.ShowDialog`. As shown below:

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
    Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

    // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
    if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
    // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
    this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        this.txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
    }
    testDialog.Dispose();
}
```